WordPress Elementor Pods data field which filters?
I have a WordPress with Pods and Elementor (pro). Filters are being applied to a data field unintentionally.
Now I want to analyze exactly which filters are being applied to this one data field.
With the Query Monitor plugin I can see that mostly Elementor filters are being applied to the content.
Is this an Elementor-specific question?
Can you write a database query that carries out such an analysis? Or is the data structure of WordPress not suitable for such analyses?
How do I find out which filters have been applied to a data field?

With the following function I show all callbacks to one or more content types.
    function logFilters(): void {
        global $wp_filter;

        $filters = [
            'the_content',
            'the_title',
            'the_excerpt',
        ];
        $log     = '';
        foreach ( $filters as $filter ) {
            $log .= "**$filter**\n";
            if ( isset( $wp_filter[ $filter ] ) ) {
                foreach ( $wp_filter[ $filter ]->callbacks as $priority => $callbacks ) {
                    foreach ( $callbacks as $callback ) {
                        if ( is_string( $callback['function'] ) ) {
                            $function_name = $callback['function'] . ' - args: ' . $callback['accepted_args'];
                        } else if ( is_array( $callback['function'] ) ) {
                            $function_name = ( is_object( $callback['function'][0] ) ? get_class( $callback['function'][0] ) : $callback['function'][0] )
                                             . '::' . $callback['function'][1] . ' - args: ' . $callback['accepted_args'];
                        } else {
                            $function_name = 'anonym';
                        }
                        $log .= "priority: $priority - function: $function_name\n";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $log .= "no Callbacks\n";
            }
            $log .= "\n";
        }
        file_put_contents( $this->filterLogFile, $log );
    }

